# bootstrap typeahead results display on multilines

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm using bootstrap 2.3.1, and I used typeahead but the results when displayed they are displayed on multi lines as the attached picture, I used the following text to generate typeahead suggestions:

```
var colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "brown", "black"];
$( "#search1" ).attr("autocomplete", "off");
$( "#search1" ).typeahead({source: colors});
```

Please advice,
[image: bootstrap typeahead error]

Comment: Check your styles, seems like `strong` tags have `display: block` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

thanx @dfsq

I did to fix that:

```
ul.typeahead strong {
  display:inline; 
}
```